# Node.js worker-farm unexpectedly stopping

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I am a pretty new developer, i was playing around with threads and I found worker-farm, worker-farm is really good for threading but I have a slight issue.
The threads work fine until it suddenly stops for no expected reason, maybe it queues so much but It firsts starts slowing down until it completely stops. I believe its a queuing issue or too many concurrent calls are called perhaps? Here is my script any help is appreciated

```
const workerFarm = require('worker-farm');
const config = require('./config.json')
setInterval(function() {
    let randomNumber = config.generalInfo.itemList[Math.floor(Math.random() * config.generalInfo.itemList.length)];
    let randomCookie = altCookies[Math.floor(Math.random() * altCookies.length)]
    workers(randomNumber, randomCookie, (err, result) => {
      let jsoned = JSON.parse(result)
        console.log(`${count++} ${jsoned.itemId} ${jsoned.price}`);
    });
}, 0);
```

Again its not a code error, its a worker-farm error that I cant seem to resolve.